# RT-N66U enable telnet on WAN interface

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, telnet

The RT-N66U Administration screen on the router's config page has an "enable telnet" option, but that seems to only allow telnet connections within the LAN (wired and wireless). I've tried connecting to the router's telnet service on the external IP and I get no response. I'm using three of these as WAPs on my LAN, so they all have static WAN addresses in the 10.0.0.0/24 network. Each router then has a separate 192.168 class C address on their respective LANs. Within each 192.168 LAN, telnet to the 192.168.[1,2,3].1 address is accessible. However, telnet to the routers on the 10.0.0.[20,30,40]/24 interfaces isn't possible.
[image: Network Diagram]

Answer (score 1):

A workaround could be:

- Plug in a raspberry pi (or something like it) on a LAN port
- Configure a port forward rule for ssh to it
- ssh to your raspberry pi and telnet to the router

Comment: I've had to resort to something like this. I have port forwarding for RDP on 3389 to various client workstations, and then I can use telnet or SSH from inside the router's LAN. Not ideal, but it works. I bought an RT-ACRH13 last week and you can enable SSH on the WAN interface to the router. Very handy.

Answer (score -1):

TELNET is a security hole, normally you *really* wouldnt want it exposed on the WAN side. Probably why the FW doesnt include a UI option for it (may still be possible from the shell, you'd have to hunt around).

Is there a reason why you're subdividing your site into three networks? A better solution might be to config the 3x 66Us as APs within your chosen subnet (10.0.0.0/22 say) and then connect them over LAN ports not WAN ports.

Comment: The Picasso of a diagram above doesn't indicate it, but there is a firewall in place where telnet can be disabled. Within the entire LAN, telnet into the WAN port of these routers doesn't provide a security concern. If I need to

Comment: (continued)...kick all the wireless users off the network for whatever reason, I have a couple options for doing it all at once. Also, I know any traffic on those 3 IPs is a wireless packet. It makes wireshark analysis a little cleaner, as I can apply a rule for or against those IPs.

Comment: Particularly if the devices are configured to be APs, telnet/ssh access from WAN would be great. For example, you could turn WiFi on and off from remote devices.